# Set max length to EditText layout_width

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm currently doing an EditText where the user can type in one row of text. But I have the issue with setting it's max length. If I set it to a specific number it becomes very unpredictable since spaces takes up more for some reason. So I can type in "asdnknfoisanfo" etc and get the correct length I want, but when you start typing with spaces between the words the length get's smaller and doesn't fill the whole EditText.

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/imageDescriptionTextEdit"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:hint="Enter a description of this picture.."
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textColorHint="#E9E9E9"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:maxEms="26"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:typeface="monospace"
            android:minEms="3"
            android:singleLine="true"
            fontPath="fonts/VarelaRound-Regular.ttf"
            tools:ignore="MissingPrefix"/>
```

What I would say to be the ultimate solution is to set the length of characters to the length of the EditText itself. Then for sure, the user have the correct capacity always. Is this possible? Or are there another solution to my problem?

Comment: You can use trim() to remove spaces and check the length

Comment: @RakshitNawani care to elaborate? It's a Java method I suppose, so how do I use it?

Comment: trim() removes only spaces at the start and the end. SO thats not gonna work@RakshitNawani

Comment: OK, instead of trim() use string.replace(" ","") it will remove all the spaces in between the strings

Comment: Can you add the code of where you are counting the text length? Need to understand why spaces are showing multiple characters on count.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this conditional

```
if(findViewById(R.id.imageDescriptionTextEdit).getText().toString().trim().length() <= "your max length here"){
    //Do something
} else {
    //Show alert message
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this.

```
String mStringStr = mEditText1.getText().toString().replaceAll("\\s", "");
```

Now you can get the actual length in string **mStringStr**(Without blank space)

```
mStringStr.length();
```

I hope this may help you.. :)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to remove the spaces from the input using below code

```
String  input = Your_EditText.getText().toString();
input = input.replace(" ", "");
```

Then you can get the length of the string using

```
int inputlength = input.length();
```

Then you can check if the input is okay or not

so , overall the code should be

```
private final TextWatcher mywatcher = new TextWatcher() {

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
       String  input = Your_EditText.getText().toString();
       input = input.replace(" ", "");
       int inputlength = input.length();
       if(inputlength>your_defined_length)
       {
          //do what you want to do 
       }

   }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
};
```

Dont forget to add this watcher to your editText

```
Your_EditText.addTextChangedListener(mywatcher);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it programatically :

```
final EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    int yourMaxLength = 10;
    boolean canNotAddMore = false;
    String maxText = "";

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if(canNotAddMore){
            et.removeTextChangedListener(this);
            et.setText(maxText);
            et.addTextChangedListener(this);
        }
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        String realCoontent = s.toString().trim().replace(" ", "");
        if(realCoontent.length() >= yourMaxLength){
            canNotAddMore = true;
            maxText = s.toString();
        }
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
    });
}
```

This example will remove the spaces from the list of characters counted to determine if the max number of characters is reached.

For example for a limit of 10 characters, the user can enter :

> "1234567890"

or

> "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0"

Answer (score 0):

You can measure the width of the typed input text with a Paint object:

```
EditText input = findViewById(R.id.imageDescriptionTextEdit) // Your EditText
final Paint paint = input.getPaint();
float textWidth = paint.measureText(input.getText().toString());
if (textWidth > input.getWidth()) {
    // Prevent further input.
}
```

You can combine this check with a TextWatcher.